# Return __getitem__ method overridden object

Tags: python, python-3.x

The requirement is to raise a custom exception when `KeyError` happens. How do I make sure that the returned object via `__getitem__()` also has similar behavior?

```
  1 class AirflowCfg(dict):
  2     def __getitem__(self, key):
  3         """
  4         This ensures that if the config isn't provided,
  5         it's an AirflowException
  6         """
  7         try:
  8             return super().__getitem__(key)
  9         except KeyError:
 10             raise AirflowException(f"{key} was not provided")
 11
 12 x = AirflowCfg({"x": {"a": 1}})
 13 print(x["x"])
 14 print(x["x"]["a"])
 15 print(x["x"]["b"])
```

The above definitely doesn't make sense and it doesn't work, output:-

```
➤ python3 foo.py
{'a': 1}
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/foo.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(x["x"]["b"])
KeyError: 'b'
```

I've this which kinda of works, but I'm sure Python has a better way.

```
class ConfigDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        This ensures that if the config isn't provided,
        it's an AirflowException
        """
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            raise AirflowException(f"{key} was not provided") from None

class AirflowCfg(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return ConfigDict(super().__getitem__(key))
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: `x["x"]` is not an `AirflowCfg` instance, it's a regular dict. `x` *is* and instance of the class. So `x["y"]` will raise a custom error. If you want children to behave this way, you need to make sure they are instances of the class as well.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks, I understand, my problem is I don't know how to do it in Python.

Comment: Mark is saying that the values of the dictionary you passed to the `AirflowCfg` must be `AirflowCfg`s themselves, not just plain dictionaries.

Comment: You can also just write a helper method to do this for nested structures

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I just wasn't thinking straight. After reading comments, It should be as easy as this:-

```
  1 class AirflowCfg(dict):
  2     def __getitem__(self, key):
  3         try:
  4             if isinstance(super().__getitem__(key), dict):
  5                 return AirflowCfg(super().__getitem__(key))
  6             else:
  7                 return super().__getitem__(key)
  8         except KeyError:
  9             raise AirflowException(f"{key} was not provided") from None
```

Comment: If this is the goal, I'd suggest calling `super().__getitem__(key)` once and storing the result, then type testing, so you don't look things up twice for every successful lookup.

Comment: instead of transforming the object into your custom class on retrieval, I think is better on storage on the `__setitem__` method and/or `__init__`, but I think the regular dict bypass the setitem for some of its methods, so to have full of that you can use the collections module like in ShadowRange example

Answer (score 0):

It's not much better, but you can simplify the `dict` wrapper returned to avoid overhead in the case where the key is found:

```
class ConfigDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):  # Called by dict.__getitem__ when the key is missing
                                 # Normally used to provide a default value, but raising
                                 # your own exception works too
        raise AirflowException(f"{key} was not provided")

class AirflowCfg(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return ConfigDict(super().__getitem__(key))
        except KeyError:
            raise AirflowException(f"{key} was not provided")
```

This *does* shallow copy the contents of the `dict` into the new `ConfigDict`. This can impose some non-trivial costs, so you may want to write a slightly more complex implementation that *contains* a `dict` rather than *inheriting* from a `dict`, so it forms a view of the underlying `dict` with just slightly different behavior, without requiring a copy operation:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class ConfigDict(MutableMapping):
    __slots__ = 'dct'
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.dct = dct
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.dct[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AirflowException(f"{key} was not provided") from None
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.dct[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.dct[key]  # Can wrap as in getitem case if desired, but you might need to implement some other methods like get, since it's provided with the assumption a missing item will raise KeyError
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.dct)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dct)
```

Comment: for the collections example, you can use `collections.UserDict` that already do exactly that (the .dct part) and just overwrite the necessary part

Comment: @Copperfield: That would work, but you'd still need to override the `__init__` to get the benefit (the provided `__init__` makes a shallow copy of the provided `initialdata` argument, so you wouldn't get the savings). Still shorter than the six methods needed for `MutableMapping`, I just didn't mention it because I always have this feeling it's "pseudo-deprecated", but I'm not confident I'm correct on that, and on checking, it's being kept up-to-date with new `dict` features, so I'm probably dead wrong. :-)